# What did the "Young Turks" bit on Money Monster mean?

Tags: analysis, cameo, money-monster

At one point in 'Money Monster', there's a brief clip of Cenk Uygur of The Young Turks. He says

> "and he got his faith on *YouTube* of all places..."

Is that supposed to mean anything? Is he talking about Kyle? I don't get it. Most of the other lines right before that seemed to be directly related to the plot.